# GUI shell script editor with function overview

Tags: user-interface, bash, editor, shell

Is there an editor for Unix shell scripts such as Bash that has a kind of function overview as most Eclipse editors? I have a really large shell script with a lot of functions here and I want to move quickly from one function to next.

Or is there any other way to get such an overview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm mostly on Windows environments I had a look to Notepad++ plugins and found the [Function List plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/). It's mainly what I'm looking for. As there is no documentation by the author have a look at an [introductory blog post](http://blog.theroyweb.com/function-list-plugin-on-notepad-53).

Answer (score 1):

The [VIM taglist plugin](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) also works for shell scripts. If you are a VIM user you might consider it...

It offers you a function list in a window split on the left, which you can use to navigate to function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Geany can hold this easily, maybe worst the effort of a linux virtual machine inside your windows, so you can use this and others tools when it comes in handy.
But Notepad++ is amazing. gedit have plugins deleveloped for this too.